# Fast evaluation of a product

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the minimum distance of a large number of point locations to a set of predefined locations (the problem is not spatial, the size of the space is >60). I have used [cKDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) for this, but in order to avoid using scipy I was wondering if there's a clever way to calculate this with numpy arrays. Looping through is easy:

```
point_locs = # Shape n_dims * n_samples
test_points = # Shape n_dims * n_points
min_dist = np.zeros ( n_points )
for i in n_points:
   min_dist[i] = np.sum(( point_locs - test_points[:,i])**2,axis=1).argmin()
```

Is there anything speedier that this? Typically, `n_points` is of the order of 10^5-10^7.

Comment: "the problem is not spatial, the size of the space is >60", do you mean the problem is not in 3D? Is the metric still Euclidian?

Comment: did you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527340/more-efficient-way-to-calculate-distance-in-numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not valid Python, and I think you are confusing your shapes... Aside from that, if you have enough memory, you can get rid of the loop by using broadcasting to vectorize the distance calculations. If you have this data:

```
n_set_points = 100
n_test_points = 10000
n_dims = 60

set_points = np.random.rand(n_set_points, n_dims) 
test_points = np.random.rand(n_test_points, n_dims)
```

Then this is the most straightforward calculation:

```
# deltas.shape = (n_set_points, n_test_point, n_dims)
deltas = (set_points[:, np.newaxis, :] -
          test_points[np.newaxis, ...])

# dist[j, k] holds the squared distance between the
# j-th set_point and the k-th test point
dist = np.sum(deltas*deltas, axis=-1)

# nearest[j] is the index of the set_point closest to
# each test_point, has shape (n_test_points,)
nearest = np.argmin(dist, axis=0)
```

The deal breaker is whether you can store `deltas` in memory: it can be a huge array. If you do, there is some performance to gain by doing the distance calculation with the more cryptic, but much more efficient:

```
dist = np.einsum('jkd,jkd->jk', deltas, deltas)
```

If `deltas` is too big, break your test_points into manageable chunks, and loop over the chunks, e.g.:

```
def nearest_neighbor(set_pts, test_pts, chunk_size):
    n_test_points = len(test_pts)
    ret = np.empty((n_test_points), dtype=np.intp)

    for chunk_start in xrange(0, n_test_points ,chunk_size):
        deltas = (set_pts[:, np.newaxis, :] -
                  test_pts[np.newaxis,
                           chunk_start:chunk_start + chunk_size, :])
        dist = np.einsum('jkd,jkd->jk', deltas,deltas)
        ret[chunk_start:chunk_start + chunk_size] = np.argmin(dist, axis=0)
    return ret

%timeit nearest_neighbor(set_points, test_points, 1)
1 loops, best of 3: 283 ms per loop

%timeit nearest_neighbor(set_points, test_points, 10)
1 loops, best of 3: 175 ms per loop

%timeit nearest_neighbor(set_points, test_points, 100)
1 loops, best of 3: 384 ms per loop

%timeit nearest_neighbor(set_points, test_points, 1000)
1 loops, best of 3: 365 ms per loop

%timeit nearest_neighbor(set_points, test_points, 10000)
1 loops, best of 3: 374 ms per loop
```

So there is some performance to gain by doing partial vectorization.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for [scipy.spatial.KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html):

> For large dimensions (20 is already large) do not expect this to run significantly faster than brute force. High-dimensional nearest-neighbor queries are a substantial open problem in computer science.

Thus, not only is it an open problem in computer science, your brute force method is most likely an adequate suboptimal option. If you can exploit some known structure in your data, i.e. all the points belong to one of n-known regions of space, than you could partition the problem down.