# Sum over squared array

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

As part of a batch Euclidean distance computation, I'm computing

```
(X * X).sum(axis=1)
```

where `X` is a rather large 2-d array. This works fine, but it constructs a temporary array of the same size as `X`. Is there any way to get rid of this temporary, but retain the efficiency of a vectorized operation?

The obvious candidate,

```
np.array([np.dot(row, row) for row in X])
```

works, but uses a Python list as a temporary, making it rather slow.

Without the `axis`, the memory-efficient form would be

```
(X * X).sum()  =>  np.dot(X.ravel(), X.ravel())
```

and I know that, when `axis=1`, it's equivalent to

```
np.diag(np.dot(X, X.T))
```

which got me looking into generalizations of `dot` such as `np.inner`, `np.tensordot` and `np.einsum`, but I can't figure out how they would solve my problem.

Comment: You should check the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527340/more-efficient-way-to-calculate-distance-in-numpy For large arrays, the memory layout becomes very important apparently

Comment: @usethedeathstar: I'm aware of that; Euclidean distance is a dot product plus the sum of two of the above operations, and the layout is already optimized for the dot product.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `einsum` equivalent is:

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i', X, X)
```

Though I am not sure how this works internally so it may or may not not solve your problem.

Comment: A first test shows that it's extremely fast. I'll do some memory profiling.

Comment: Einsum is probably one of the best functions numpy has for handling large arrays. It is compiled entirely in C and takes advantage of `SSE2` which numpy's ufuncs will not use until 1.8. Also it does try to avoid holding large numpy intermediates in memory. Source code is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6f9a41276153187a4c6e45eb0b8a9999d946608d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src).

Comment: The other alternative is `inner1d`: `numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d; inner1d(X, X)`, but `np.einsum` is faster most of the time, or on most systems.

Comment: @Jaime: is that even supposed to be a public function?

Comment: I think it is still experimental, but it is here to stay. `inner1d` and `matrix_multiply` are the two first instances of gufuncs, where the 'g' is for 'generalized', [here's what the API docs say](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.generalized-ufuncs.html). In numpy 1.8 there will be a whole batch of linear algebra gufuncs, including those two, [browse the PR](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/2954/files) to see what will be added. Best thing of gufuncs is they make it really, really easy to extend numpy with C when you are dealing with more complicated algorithms.

Comment: `einsum` uses an `nditer` to efficiently iterate on a row (or column, depending on ordering) of `X`, doing `o[...]=(x*x).sum()` each time.  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3142