# Fastest pairwise distance metric in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have an 1D array of numbers, and want to calculate all pairwise euclidean distances. I have a method (thanks to SO) of doing this with broadcasting, but it's inefficient because it calculates each distance twice. And it doesn't scale well.

Here's an example that gives me what I want with an array of 1000 numbers.

```
import numpy as np
import random
r = np.array([random.randrange(1, 1000) for _ in range(0, 1000)])
dists = np.abs(r - r[:, None])
```

What's the fastest implementation in scipy/numpy/scikit-learn that I can use to do this, given that it has to scale to situations where the 1D array has >10k values.

Note: the matrix is symmetric, so I'm guessing that it's possible to get at least a 2x speedup by addressing that, I just don't know how.

Comment: There's a function for that: [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html). I dunno whether this is the fastest option, since it needs to have checks for multidimensional data, non-Euclidean norms, and other things, but it's built in.

Comment: How fast do you need this to be? It's never going to scale better than O(n^2), since you have to populate n^2 entries of output. Your existing solution is O(n^2), and there doesn't seem to be much room for major optimizations.

Comment: This seems to scale to >10k values well enough already when I try it. Remember that you need to populate 100 million entries of output. That's almost half a gigabyte of pairwise distances.

Comment: seconded to @user2357112 and @askewchan, but make sure your `numpy` is  compiled with BLAS or MKL, the one you download straightly from sourceforge is likely not.

Comment: @askewchan I don't think it does... If you follow the source code, in the end [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/spatial/src/distance.c#L44) is the function getting called. Not only is there no fancy optimization, but for 1D vectors it is squaring and taking the square root to compute the absolute value. Probably worse than the OP's code for his particular use case.

Comment: @CTZhu If I'm not mistaken, `scipy` is always compiled with BLAS, it's not optional as with `numpy`.

Comment: @Jaime Ah, I stand corrected.  Thanks for actually looking it up :)

Comment: On the other hand, calling `pdist` with `'cityblock'` for the metric should do the trick.

Comment: Did you check this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527340/more-efficient-way-to-calculate-distance-in-numpy There i had a similar problem, when the arrays get big, you have to abuse memory layout to get speedups

Comment: @askewchan: `scipy.spatial.distance` only calls BLAS for a limited number of cases, and only after doing some more operations because BLAS has no distance functions. It's not faster for the OP's use case.

Comment: You're correct @larsmans, as Jaime has also said.  I have deleted the comment.

Comment: do you mind giving a link the question you are referring to? What post in SO?

Comment: sorry - this was so long ago that I don't remember what original post it was. But I do know it was somewhere on SO!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Neither of the other answers quite answered the question - 1 was in Cython, one was slower. But both provided very useful hints. Following up on them suggests that `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` is the way to go.

Here's some code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import sklearn.metrics.pairwise
import scipy.spatial.distance

r = np.array([random.randrange(1, 1000) for _ in range(0, 1000)])
c = r[:, None]

def option1(r):
    dists = np.abs(r - r[:, None])

def option2(r):
    dists = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(r, 'cityblock')

def option3(r):
    dists = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances(r)
```

Timing with IPython:

```
In [36]: timeit option1(r)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.31 ms per loop

In [37]: timeit option2(c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop

In [38]: timeit option3(c)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop
```

I didn't try the Cython implementation (I can't use it for this project), but comparing my results to the other answer that did, it looks like `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` is roughly a third slower than the Cython implementation (taking into account the different machines by benchmarking on the np.abs solution).

Comment: I assume this is as fast as: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html ? the version in sklearn?

Comment: In the scipy.spatial.distance.pdist case, should it be c instead of r?

Comment: @learner I think so

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Cython implementation that gives more than 3X speed improvement for this example on my computer. This timing should be reviewed for bigger arrays tough, because the BLAS routines can probably scale much better than this rather naive code.

I know you asked for something inside scipy/numpy/scikit-learn, but maybe this will open new possibilities for you:

File `my_cython.pyx`:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double abs(double t)

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def pairwise_distance(np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] r):
    cdef int i, j, c, size
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] ans
    size = sum(range(1, r.shape[0]+1))
    ans = np.empty(size, dtype=r.dtype)
    c = -1
    for i in range(r.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i, r.shape[0]):
            c += 1
            ans[c] = abs(r[i] - r[j])
    return ans
```

The answer is a 1-D array containing all non-repeated evaluations.

To import into Python:

```
import numpy as np
import random

import pyximport; pyximport.install()
from my_cython import pairwise_distance

r = np.array([random.randrange(1, 1000) for _ in range(0, 1000)], dtype=float)

def solOP(r):
    return np.abs(r - r[:, None])
```

Timing with IPython:

```
In [2]: timeit solOP(r)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.38 ms per loop

In [3]: timeit pairwise_distance(r)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 ms per loop
```

Comment: Surely you meant `fabs` -- `abs` is `int` variant.

Answer (score 7):

Using half the memory, but 6 times slower than `np.abs(r - r[:, None])`:

```
triu = np.triu_indices(r.shape[0],1)
dists2 = abs(r[triu[1]]-r[triu[0]])
```