# Optimizing pairwise calculation of distances an array for a given shift

Tags: python, arrays, performance, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array containing millions of entries. 
I would like to calculate a another vector, containing all of the distances, for pairs of entries, that are shifted by a certain number delta in the array.

Actually I'm using this:

```
for i in range(0, len(a) - delta):
    difs = numpy.append(difs, a[i + self.delta] - a[i])
```

Does anyone know how to do this faster?

There's a similar question here: 
[Fastest pairwise distance metric in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277982/fastest-pairwise-distance-metric-in-python)

But I don't want to calculate the distance for every pair.

Example:

```
>>> a = [1,5,7,7,2,6]
>>> delta = 2
>>> print difs
array([ 6.,  2., -5., -1.])
```

Comment: whats your python version ?

Comment: It would be useful to see an example of input and your expected output - are you able to post a small example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just slice `a` using `delta` and then subtract the two subarrays:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,5,7,7,2,6])
>>> delta = 2
>>> a[delta:] - a[:-delta]
array([ 6,  2, -5, -1])
```

This slicing operation is likely to be very quick for large arrays as no additional indexes or copies of the data in `a` needs to be created. The subtraction creates a new array with the required values in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` is a numpy.array, one could probably get the same result with indexing all pairs at once. This is a vectorized numpy solution.

```
a = numpy.atleast_1d(a)  #// make sure a is a numpy array
idx_minuend = range(delta, len(a))
idx_subtrahend = range(0, len(a)-delta)
difs = a[idx_minuend] - a[idx_subtrahend]
```

A little tests verifies that the results are the same:

```
# // a little test with your data
import numpy
a = [1,5,7,7,2,6]
delta = 2

# // current version
difs = numpy.array([])
for i in range(0, len(a) - delta):
    difs = numpy.append(difs, a[i + delta] - a[i])

# // numpy vectorized version
a = numpy.atleast_1d(a)  #// make sure a is a numpy array
idx_minuend = range(delta, len(a))
idx_subtrahend = range(0, len(a)-delta)
difs2 = a[idx_minuend] - a[idx_subtrahend]

# // compare results
(difs == difs2).all()  # True
```