# Efficiently compute n-body gravitation in python

Tags: python, numpy, simulation, physics

I am trying to compute the accelerations due to gravity for an n-body problem in 3-space (I'm using symplectic Euler).

I have position and velocity vectors for each time step, and am using the below (working) code to calculate accelerations and update velocity and position. Note that the accelerations are vectors in 3-space, not just magnitudes.

I would like to know if there's a more efficient way to compute this with numpy to avoid the loops.

```
def accelerations(positions, masses):
    '''Params:
    - positions: numpy array of size (n,3)
    - masses: numpy array of size (n,)
    Returns:
    - accelerations: numpy of size (n,3), the acceleration vectors in 3-space
    '''
    n_bodies = len(masses)
    accelerations = numpy.zeros([n_bodies,3]) # n_bodies * (x,y,z)

    # vectors from mass(i) to mass(j)
    D = numpy.zeros([n_bodies,n_bodies,3]) # n_bodies * n_bodies * (x,y,z)
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_bodies), range(n_bodies)):
        D[i][j] = positions[j]-positions[i]

    # Acceleration due to gravitational force between each pair of bodies
    A = numpy.zeros((n_bodies, n_bodies,3))
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_bodies), range(n_bodies)):
        if numpy.linalg.norm(D[i][j]) > epsilon:
            A[i][j] = gravitational_constant * masses[j] * D[i][j] \
            / numpy.linalg.norm(D[i][j])**3

    # Calculate net acceleration of each body (vectors in 3-space)
    accelerations = numpy.sum(A, axis=1) # sum of accel vectors for each body of shape (n_bodies,3)

    return accelerations
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest pairwise distance metric in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277982/fastest-pairwise-distance-metric-in-python)

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate, but to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277982/fastest-pairwise-distance-metric-in-python, (and, ultimately) https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

Comment: As for the acceleration portion, you'd simply use a call to `np.where` combined with a a "mass matrix" that you can get by doing: `masses.reshape((1, -1))*masses.reshape((-1, 1))`.

Comment: I think pdist just gives the magnitude of the vectors. Since I want to add the forces in 3-space, I also need to retain the directions.

Comment: The best algorithm depends on epsilon and on the number of point-masses. On at least medium sized problems I recommend to use a kd-tree https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html to find point-masses which are in a given range to each other and calculate the gravitiational force only on them. This is much faster than calculating useless distances. For the rest I would recommend a simple Numba approach. Can you provide resonable testdata (positions, masses, epsilon) since this has a huge effect on runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an optimized version using `blas`. `blas` has special routines for linear algebra on symmetric or Hermitian matrices. These use specialized, packed storage, keeping only the upper or lower triangle and leaving out the (redundant) mirrored entries. That way blas saves not only ~half the storage but also ~half the flops.

I've put quite a few comments to make it readable.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from scipy.linalg.blas import zhpr, dspr2, zhpmv

def acc_vect(pos, mas):
    n = mas.size
    d2 = pos@(-2*pos.T)
    diag = -0.5 * np.einsum('ii->i', d2)
    d2 += diag + diag[:, None]
    np.einsum('ii->i', d2)[...] = 1
    return np.nansum((pos[:, None, :] - pos) * (mas[:, None] * d2**-1.5)[..., None], axis=0)

def acc_blas(pos, mas):
    n = mas.size
    # trick: use complex Hermitian to get the packed anti-symmetric
    # outer difference in the imaginary part of the zhpr answer
    # don't want to sum over dimensions yet, therefore must do them one-by-one
    trck = np.zeros((3, n * (n + 1) // 2), complex)
    for a, p in zip(trck, pos.T - 1j):
        zhpr(n, -2, p, a, 1, 0, 0, 1)
        # does  a  ->  a + alpha x x^H
        # parameters: n             --  matrix dimension
        #             alpha         --  real scalar
        #             x             --  complex vector
        #             ap            --  packed Hermitian n x n matrix a
        #                               i.e. an n(n+1)/2 vector
        #             incx          --  x stride
        #             offx          --  x offset
        #             lower         --  is storage of ap lower or upper
        #             overwrite_ap  --  whether to change a inplace
    # as a by-product we get pos pos^T:
    ppT = trck.real.sum(0) + 6
    # now compute matrix of squared distances ...
    # ... using (A-B)^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2AB
    # ... that and the outer sum X (+) X.T equals X ones^T + ones X^T
    dspr2(n, -0.5, ppT[np.r_[0, 2:n+1].cumsum()], np.ones((n,)), ppT,
          1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    # does  a  ->  a + alpha x y^T + alpha y x^T    in packed symmetric storage
    # scale anti-symmetric differences by distance^-3
    np.divide(trck.imag, ppT*np.sqrt(ppT), where=ppT.astype(bool),
              out=trck.imag)
    # it remains to scale by mass and sum
    # this can be done by matrix multiplication with the vector of masses ...
    # ... unfortunately because we need anti-symmetry we need to work
    # with Hermitian storage, i.e. complex numbers, even though the actual
    # computation is only real:
    out = np.zeros((3, n), complex)
    for a, o in zip(trck, out):
        zhpmv(n, 0.5, a, mas*-1j, 1, 0, 0, o, 1, 0, 0, 1)
        # multiplies packed Hermitian matrix by vector
    return out.real.T

def accelerations(positions, masses, epsilon=1e-6, gravitational_constant=1.0):
    '''Params:
    - positions: numpy array of size (n,3)
    - masses: numpy array of size (n,)
    '''
    n_bodies = len(masses)
    accelerations = np.zeros([n_bodies,3]) # n_bodies * (x,y,z)

    # vectors from mass(i) to mass(j)
    D = np.zeros([n_bodies,n_bodies,3]) # n_bodies * n_bodies * (x,y,z)
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_bodies), range(n_bodies)):
        D[i][j] = positions[j]-positions[i]

    # Acceleration due to gravitational force between each pair of bodies
    A = np.zeros((n_bodies, n_bodies,3))
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(n_bodies), range(n_bodies)):
        if np.linalg.norm(D[i][j]) > epsilon:
            A[i][j] = gravitational_constant * masses[j] * D[i][j] \
            / np.linalg.norm(D[i][j])**3

    # Calculate net accleration of each body
    accelerations = np.sum(A, axis=1) # sum of accel vectors for each body

    return accelerations

from numpy.linalg import norm

def acc_pm(positions, masses, G=1):
    '''Params:
    - positions: numpy array of size (n,3)
    - masses: numpy array of size (n,)
    '''
    mass_matrix = masses.reshape((1, -1, 1))*masses.reshape((-1, 1, 1))
    disps = positions.reshape((1, -1, 3)) - positions.reshape((-1, 1, 3)) # displacements
    dists = norm(disps, axis=2)
    dists[dists == 0] = 1 # Avoid divide by zero warnings
    forces = G*disps*mass_matrix/np.expand_dims(dists, 2)**3
    return forces.sum(axis=1)/masses.reshape(-1, 1)

n = 500
pos = np.random.random((n, 3))
mas = np.random.random((n,))

from timeit import timeit

print(f"loops:      {timeit('accelerations(pos, mas)', globals=globals(), number=1)*1000:10.3f} ms")
print(f"pmende:     {timeit('acc_pm(pos, mas)', globals=globals(), number=10)*100:10.3f} ms")
print(f"vectorized: {timeit('acc_vect(pos, mas)', globals=globals(), number=10)*100:10.3f} ms")
print(f"blas:       {timeit('acc_blas(pos, mas)', globals=globals(), number=10)*100:10.3f} ms")

A = accelerations(pos, mas)
AV = acc_vect(pos, mas)
AB = acc_blas(pos, mas)
AP = acc_pm(pos, mas)

assert np.allclose(A, AV) and np.allclose(AB, AV) and np.allclose(AP, AV)
```

Sample run; comparing to OP, my pure numpy vectorization and @P Mende's.

```
loops:        3213.130 ms
pmende:         41.480 ms
vectorized:     43.860 ms
blas:            7.726 ms
```

We can see that

1) P Mende is slightly better than I at vectorizing

2) `blas` is **~5 times** as fast; please note that my blas is not very good; I suspect with an optimized blas you may get even better (numpy would be expected to run faster too on a better blas, though)

3) any of the answers is much faster than loops

Comment: That's pretty cool. I don't really understand the math you've done here, or why it's so much faster though. Are there any resources you'd recommend to get smarter about this?

Comment: @PaulDickinson I've added a tiny bit of general explanation to the answer addressing why blas is so much faster here. For details I'm not aware of any magic resources. The math is just a bit of linear algebra. For blas routines one has to look at http://www.netlib.org/blas/ and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.blas.html.

Comment: I was thinking more of what is going on with the complex hermitian. I understand the words, but this application is not something I’m familiar with!

Comment: @PaulDickinson ah, ok that's just a bit of evil trickery: Say `x` is the vector of x coordinates. Then we need 1 the outer difference `x-x[None, :]`, ideally in packed storage and 2 the outer product x@x[None, :] (also packed if possible) because these terms occur in the Euclidean distances. Now, by adding the imaginary unit `1j` to x and then taking the Hermitian outer product we get a Hermititan matrix that has as i,k-entry `(x_i + 1j)(x_k - 1j) = (x_i x_k + 1) + 1j(x_k - x_i)`, so the imaginary part gives us the outer difference and the real part gives us the outer product up to an offset.

Answer (score 5):

A follow up to my comments on your original post:

```
from numpy.linalg import norm

def accelerations(positions, masses):
    '''Params:
    - positions: numpy array of size (n,3)
    - masses: numpy array of size (n,)
    '''
    mass_matrix = masses.reshape((1, -1, 1))*masses.reshape((-1, 1, 1))
    disps = positions.reshape((1, -1, 3)) - positions.reshape((-1, 1, 3)) # displacements
    dists = norm(disps, axis=2)
    dists[dists == 0] = 1 # Avoid divide by zero warnings
    forces = G*disps*mass_matrix/np.expand_dims(dists, 2)**3
    return forces.sum(axis=1)/masses.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, both pdist and np.where are good to know about! This doesn't actually quite solve the problem though, as the output should be vectors in 3-space, not just their magnitudes. That's also why there was a cube rather than square factor in the original code.

Comment: @PaulDickinson Ah, right. My apologies. I've updated the answer to have the right shape.

Comment: (There's actually still a problem with broadcasting. I'll update in a minute.)

Comment: @PaulDickinson It should work now. Mostly it's an exercise in clever reshaping/broadcasting.

Comment: Nice, that's much more elegant than original solution!

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider:

You only need half the distances; once you've calculated `D[i][j]`, that's the same as `-D[j][i]`.

You can do `df2 = df.apply(lambda x:gravitational_constant/x**3)`

You can generate a dataframe that records, for each pair of bodies, the product of their masses. You only have do that once, and then you can pass it to `accelearations` every time you call it.

Then `df.product(df2).product(mass_products).sum().div(masses)` gives you the accelerations.