# Fastest way to calculate Euclidean and Minkowski distance between all the vectors in a list of lists python

Tags: python, numpy, distance, euclidean-distance

I have been trying for a while now to calculate the Euclidean and Minkowski distance between all the vectors in a list of lists. I don't have much advanced mathematical knowledge.

- I am usually working with 4 or 5 dimension vectors
- The vector list can range in size from 0 to around 200,000
- When calculating the distance all the vectors will have the same amount of dimensions

I have relied on these two questions during the process:

[python numpy euclidean distance calculation between matrices of row vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370975/python-numpy-euclidean-distance-calculation-between-matrices-of-row-vectors)

[Calculate Euclidean Distance between all the elements in a list of lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59941250/calculate-euclidean-distance-between-all-the-elements-in-a-list-of-lists-python)

At first my code looked like this:

```
import numpy as np

def euclidean_distance_np(vec_list, single_vec):
    dist = (np.array(vec_list) - single_vec) ** 2
    dist = np.sum(dist, axis=1)
    dist = np.sqrt(dist)
    return dist

def minkowski_distance_np(vec_list, single_vec, p_val):
    dist = (np.abs(np.array(vec_list, dtype=np.int64) - single_vec) ** p_val).sum(axis=1) ** (1 / p_val)
    return dist
```

This worked well when I had a small amount of vectors. I would calculate the distance of a single vector to all the vectors in the list and repeat the process for every vector in the list one by one,
but once the list became 5 or 6 digits in length, these functions became extremely slow.

I managed to improve the Euclidean distance calculation like so:

```
x = np.array([v[0] for v in vec_list])
y = np.array([v[1] for v in vec_list])
z = np.array([v[2] for v in vec_list])
w = np.array([v[3] for v in vec_list])
t = np.array([v[4] for v in vec_list])

res = np.sqrt(np.square(x - x.reshape(-1,1)) + np.square(y - y.reshape(-1,1)) + np.square(z - z.reshape(-1,1)) + np.square(w - w.reshape(-1,1)) + np.square(t - t.reshape(-1,1)))
```

But cannot figure out how to implement the calculation method above to correctly calculate Minkowski distance.
So, to be precise, my question is how can I calculate Minkowski distance in a similar way to the code I mentioned above.

I would also appreciate any ideas for improvement or better ways to preform the calculations

Comment: For simple arrays (2x 2d) (not lists) this is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58752553/4045774 using numba.

Answer (score 1):

Scipy has already implemented distance functions: [minkowski](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.minkowski.html), [euclidean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean). But probably what you need is [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

Numpy is great tool for matrices manipulation, but it doesn't contain all possible functions. You can find most of additional features and operations in [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html) which is more related to mathematics, science, and engineering.

Comment: great reference, unfortunately got Memory Error on large matrices