# Efficient pairwise sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am looking for a way to optimize the following code. It computes all the possible pairwise sums of the elements in an array:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

N = 5000
a = np.random.rand(N)

c = ([a[i]+a[j] for i,j in combinations(range(N),2)])
```

This is relatively slow. I could get much better performances using the following:

```
b = a+a[:,None]
c = b[np.triu_indices(N,1)]
```

yet it still seems largely non-optimized: computing the full matrix b is inefficient because half of it ends up useless, and extracting its upper part (omitting the diagonal) is actually even slower than computing b.

Is there a way to do this faster? This makes me think of a similar problem, computing pairwise distances between points ([Fastest pairwise distance metric in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277982/fastest-pairwise-distance-metric-in-python)) but I don't know if there is a way to do something similar here using scipy.

edit: I would like to keep the order of the sums, so that the result contains the sum of the indices in this order:
[(0,1), (0,2), ... (0,N-1), (1,2), .... (1,N-1), (2,3), ...],
i.e. the order you would get doing a double for loop `for 0=<i<N, for  j<i<N`

Comment: `sklearn` is part of `scipy`, or at least an extension.  `numpy/scipy` does not have a fast compiled method for iterating on upper/lower triangles.  `sklearn` wrote its own.  `C` code intuitions about efficiency (counting every addition, etc) don't apply in `numpy`.  The fast stuff is coded to work with 'whole' arrays; fancy indexing can slow it down.

Comment: Is the order in which the sums are computed important?

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, I am still fairly new to python so that is good general information to know. I'll look into sklearn.

Comment: @PaulPanzer It is, I updated the question.

Comment: @StevePoney I have the exact requirements. Have you found any better solution? If scipy's pdist had a manhattan distance that add coordinates, instead of subtracting them, it would be perfect.