# Best way to calculate l2 norm between two 2d arrays in numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to come up with a fast way to `calculate l2 distance between the rows of two 2d numpy arrays`. So first 2d numpy array is `7000 x 100` and second 2d numpy array is `4000 x 100`.

I want to get a matrix of `4000 x 7000`, where each `(i, j)` entry is a `l2 norm between ith row of second 2d numpy array and jth row of first 2d numpy array`.

I am assuming I probably have to use `numpy.linalg.norm`, but am not quite sure on how to vectorize the operation.

Thanks for the help! Let me know if the question is unclear in any ways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest pairwise distance metric in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277982/fastest-pairwise-distance-metric-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in scipy designed specifically for finding all distances between two sets of vectors:

```py
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(a, b)
```

Comment: Hi! I do not think matrix multiplication will work because I need to get the Euclidean distance between 2 row vectors.

Comment: Fixed now, please change norm to distance in your question, it’s confusing otherwise