# Improving runtime performance of pairwise euclidean distance with cython

Tags: python, cython, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate pairwise euclidean distances between two sets of D-Dimensional Vectors and trying to optimize the runtime performance of the below naive implementation. 
Basically the below code returns the pairwise squared euclidean distance between each row in descriptors(AxD) with each row in codebook (BxD) returning a result (AxB) matrix.

By moving from python to cython based implementation i see a good improvement. I am new to cython and was wondering if this implementation could be further optimized to bring performance closer to pure c or java based implementation.

pairwise_dist.pyx

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import math
import cython
np.import_array()
DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

def _pdist(   np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] codebook,
              np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] descriptors,
              np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] result  ):

            cdef int i, j, k
            cdef int codebook_size = codebook.shape[0]
            cdef int n_descriptors = descriptors.shape[0]
            cdef int n_dimensions = codebook.shape[1]

            cdef float dist, diff

            for i in xrange(n_descriptors):
                for j in xrange(codebook_size):
                    dist = 0.0
                    for k in xrange(n_dimensions):
                        diff = codebook[j,k] - descriptors[i,k]
                        dist = dist + diff*diff
                    result[i,j] = dist
```

test.py:

```
import time
import numpy
CODEBOOK_SIZE = 4096
CODEBOOK_DIM = 64
DESC_DIM = 64
DESC_SIZE = 4000

codebook = numpy.random.randint(256,size=(CODEBOOK_SIZE,CODEBOOK_DIM))
descriptors = numpy.random.randint(256,size=(DESC_SIZE,DESC_DIM))
codebook = codebook.astype(numpy.float64)
descriptors = descriptors.astype(numpy.float64)

result = numpy.zeros((descriptors.shape[0],codebook.shape[0]),codebook.dtype)
from pairwise_dist import _pdist

stime = time.time()
_pdist(codebook,descriptors,result)
etime = time.time()
print "Time taken: "+ str(stime-etime)
```

build.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = "pairwise_dist",
    ext_modules = cythonize('pairwise_dist.pyx'),
)
```

python build_cython.py build_ext --inplace

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527340/more-efficient-way-to-calculate-distance-in-numpy I compared six different methods to calculate the distance there, to find out which is faster

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cython for educational reasons? Otherwise, I'd recommend using the scipy.spatial module

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

object_1 = [0.2, 4.5, 198, 0.003]
object_2 = [0.3, 2.0, 999, 0.001]
object_3 = [0.1, 9.2, 321, 0.023]
list_of_objects = [object_1, object_2, object_3]

# make a 4x3 matrix from list of objects
X = np.array(list_of_objects)

#calculate pairwise distances
distances = pdist(X)

#make a square matrix from result
distances_as_2d_matrix = squareform(distances)

print distances
print distances_as_2d_matrix
```

`pdist` supports multiple metrics, euclidean being only one.