# calculate euclidean distance for PCA in python

Tags: python, numpy, pca, euclidean-distance

I have PCA with 3D `numpy array` as

```
pcar =[[xa ya za]
       [xb yb zb]
       [xc yc zc]
       .
       .
       [xn yn zn]]
```

where each row is a point and I have selected any two random rows from above `PCA` as a cluster as

```
out_list=pcar[numpy.random.randint(0,pcar.shape[0],2)]
```

which gives numpy array with 2 rows.

I have to find euclidean distance from each row of out_list with each row(point) in pcar and add that pcar point to nearest point in out_list cluster.

Comment: What happens if two points have the same x,y,z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really fast implementation in [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html):

```
 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist
```

cdist takes two vectors like your pchar one and calculates the distances betweeen each of these points.
pdist will give you only the upper triangle of that matrix.

As they are implemented in C or Fortran behind the scenes, they are very performant.

Comment: See also the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527340/more-efficient-way-to-calculate-distance-in-numpy If your arrays become huge, than those methods are not the best to use.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**
Ok, I downloaded, installed and taught myself numpy. Here is a numpy version

*Old answer*

I realise you want a numpy answer. My numpy is rusty, but since there are no other answers, I thought I'd give you one in Matlab. It should be straightforward to convert. I'm assuming the issue is the concept, not the code.

Note there are many ways to skin this cat, I'm just giving one.

**Working Numpy version**

```
import numpy as np

pcar = np.random.rand(10,3)

out_list=pcar[np.random.randint(0,pcar.shape[0],2)]

ol_1 = out_list[0,:]
ol_2 = out_list[1,:]

## Get the individual distances
## The trick here is to pre-multiply the 1x3 ol vector with a row of
## ones of size 10x1 to get a 10x3 array with ol replicated, so that it
## can simply be subtracted
d1 = pcar - ones( size(pcar,1))*ol_1
d2 = pcar - ones( size(pcar,1))*ol_2

##% Square them using an element-wise square
d1s = np.square(d1)
d2s = np.square(d2)

##% Sum across the rows, not down columns
d1ss = np.sum(d1s, axis=1)
d2ss = np.sum(d2s, axis=1)

##% Square root using an element-wise square-root
e1 = np.sqrt(d1ss)
e2 = np.sqrt(d2ss)

##% Assign to class one or class two
##% Start by assigning one to everything, then select all those where ol_2
##% is closer and assign them the number 2
assign = ones(size(e1,0));
assign[e2<e1] = 2

##% Separate
pcar1 = pcar[ assign==1, :]
pcar2 = pcar[ assign==2, :]
```

**Working Matlab version**

```
close all
clear all

% Create 10 records each with 3 attributes
pcar = rand(10, 3)

% Pick two (normally at random of course)
out_list = pcar(1:2, :)

% Hard-coding this separately, though this can be done iteratively
ol_1 = out_list(1,:)
ol_2 = out_list(2,:)

% Get the individual distances
% The trick here is to pre-multiply the 1x3 ol vector with a row of
% ones of size 10x1 to get a 10x3 array with ol replicated, so that it
% can simply be subtracted
d1 = pcar - ones( size(pcar,1), 1)*ol_1
d2 = pcar - ones( size(pcar,1), 1)*ol_2

% Square them using an element-wise square
d1s = d1.^2
d2s = d2.^2

% Sum across the rows, not down columns
d1ss = sum(d1s, 2)
d2ss = sum(d2s, 2)

% Square root using an element-wise square-root
e1 = sqrt(d1ss)
e2 = sqrt(d2ss)

% Assign to class one or class two
% Start by assigning one to everything, then select all those where ol_2
% is closer and assign them the number 2
assign = ones(length(e1),1);
assign(e2<e1)=2

% Separate
pcar1 = pcar( assign==1, :)
pcar2 = pcar( assign==2, :)

% Plot
plot3(pcar1(:,1), pcar1(:,2), pcar1(:,3), 'g+')
hold on
plot3(pcar2(:,1), pcar2(:,2), pcar2(:,3), 'r+')
plot3(ol_1(1), ol_1(2), ol_1(3), 'go')
plot3(ol_2(1), ol_2(2), ol_2(3), 'ro')
```

Comment: As useful as this is it doesn't answer the OP's question as they require it in python, good effort nonetheless

Comment: @EdChum I realise that the OP is using numpy. If the problem is the concept, then an answer in pseudo-code would do just fine. If pseudo-code would do fine, why not Matlab, which is the first cousin of numpy? Anyway, I figured it can't hurt.

Comment: @EdChum OK, I've provided a numpy version. It is a credit to stackoverflow and python that I could download, install, and learn enough numpy to translate my code in about 30m!

Comment: @timbo It gives two arrays with pcar which contains 1 less row and another array with single row which is the removed array from pcar.

Comment: @DummyGuy If you are using the code exactly as it is, with the random test case, it might split it 1:9 by chance. The test data is random and so are the seeds. I've tried it just now and my results are correct. pcar1 holds all the vectors closest to ol_1, and pcar2 holds all the vectors closest to ol_2. The distances are in e1 and e2. You can replace the random calls with your own data to test.

Comment: @timbo you should not use 'from numpy import * ', and especially not right after you did "import numpy as np". Other than that, you could improve readability by doing "d1s = d1**2", and "e1 = d1ss**0.5", instead of the syntax you are using. It is clear that you only know numpy for 30min, but give it another 30min, and you will love it, and another 30min later you will realize that matlab is pointless and just taking up diskspace, and that money can be spent better on other stuff than matlab license fees ;-). Welcome to numpy, it will blow your mind.

Comment: @usethedeathstar Thanks. I was trying to reproduce the Matlab. I did figure I basically imported twice. The import as np was from an example on numpy.org.