# Faster alternative to numpy.einsum for taking the "element-wise" dot product of two lists of vectors?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say you're given two arrays of vectors:

`v1 = np.array([ [1, 2], [3, 4] ])`
`v2 = np.array([ [10, 20], [30, 40]])`

We would like to generate an array that is equivalent to:

`v3 = np.array([ np.dot(v1[0], v2[0]), np.dot(v1[1], v2[1]) ])`

Currently I use:

`v3 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v1, v2)`

However, I do this *a lot* in my code, so speed ups here would be very helpful for me.

How could we speed it up? `np.einsum` is already quite efficient, but I wonder if for *this particular use-case*, there is a faster way?

Comment: If your arrays are really big, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527340/more-efficient-way-to-calculate-distance-in-numpy To see some comparisons of numpy.einsum to other ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`einsum` does the best of 3 options that I can think of:

```
In [73]: timeit v3=np.einsum('ij,ij->i',v1,v2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.14 us per loop

In [74]: timeit np.diag(np.dot(v1,v2.T))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.43 us per loop

In [75]: timeit np.sum(v1*v2,axis=1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.8 us per loop
```

Several questions to ask:

- is this calculation really that expensive ?
- if it is relatively expensive do you have to doing so often ?
- can you consolidate the `einsum` calls - concatenate arrays ?

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer. Actually, suggestion 3 might be possible. Here is a post about the use-case: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54347/how-can-i-optimize-a-function-i-wrote-to-calculate-element-wise-the-angles-bet

Answer (score 1):

Try inner1d

```
import numpy as np
import cProfile
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

v1 = np.random.random((10**7,2,))  # 10 million random vectors
v2 = np.random.random((10**7,2,))  # 10 million random vectors
v3 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v1, v2) # einsum
v4 = inner1d(v1,v2)                # inner1d (~2x faster than einsum)

cProfile.run("np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v1, v2)") # cProfile: 3 function calls in 0.065 seconds
cProfile.run("inner1d(v1,v2)") # cProfile: 2 function calls in 0.033 seconds

print np.allclose(v3,v4) # Returns True
```